# Since the beginning of 2021 I get sometimes d????????? (question marks) for linux file permissions; a reboot resolves it

Tags: kernel, permissions, filesystem, ext4, fsck

since the beginning of 2021 I get for my ubunut 18.04 bionic from time to time for different directories the situation that the directories and files show up with file permissions d????????? (nine question marks). I noticed this up to now only in directories that are under the control of git, but I am not sure if other directories are also affected. A reboot resolves this situation. This is on my root partition on ext4.

An fsck via /forcefsck gives "Log of fsck -C -a -T -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2 ... clean".

At the beginning of the year were some kernel updates. Are there any kernel issues known that would explain this behaviour?

Google is also not very helpful, because you cannot search for question marks.

Thanks a lot for any help!
Christian

Comment: uname -a gives: Linux x99 4.15.0-130-generic #134-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 5 20:46:26 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: If this is happening *just* with the `.git` directories (and files within), then it's most likely due to background processes locking the files while writes and whatnot take place. Another possibility would be that something (or someone) has removed the `+X` flag from the directory(ies), which can lead to a similar results.

Comment: It is mostly happening with files under the control of git, but not in the .git directory, but once it also happened in the .git directory. After a reboot everything is fine again and the +x for the directories is there.

Comment: Just an intermediate report: on 2021-01-15 there was another kernel update and since then I did not see the problem again:

uname -a Linux x99 4.15.0-132-generic #136-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 14:58:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It just happened again. At the moment the kernel version is: uname -a Linux x99 4.15.0-134-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 10:52:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've now seen it for the first time in a folder that is not related to git at all.
uname -a 
Linux x99 4.15.0-135-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:38:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated a few weeks ago to the HWE kernel 5.4.0 and since then the problem is gone. There was never a data loss and after a reboot the problem affected other files than before. I guess that the problem was due to some issues with kernel buffers in connection to fscrypt that I use. I consider this problem as solved now.